# Nested Conditional Panels in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

Hey Im trying to nest ConditionalPanels within ConditionalPanels. The output is showing everything in the first Conditional panel and completely disregarding the conditional panels within. 
Desired flow of Output: Choose Marketing(SMS or Email) -> Auto or Manual -> Either Auto or Manual layout (not both). [image: Current Output]
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    fluid = TRUE,
    width = 3,

```
h3("Marketing", style = "align:center;text-align:center;text-shadow: 2px
   2px #FFFFFF"),
hr(style = "border-top: dotted 1px #FFFFFF"),

#################################################################################################
selectInput(
  "WeekdayMarketingChoice",
  "Please Select Marketing Type",
  choices = c("Email Marketing" = "emailMarketing", "SMS Marketing" =
                "smsMarketing"),
  2
),


br(),

####  Mai ConditionalPanel for SMS Marketing
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.WeekdayMarketingChoice == 'smsMarketing'",
  selectInput(
    "automanualsms",
    "Auto or Manual",
    choices = c("Automatic", "Manual"),
    1
  )
  ,
  #nested conditionalpanel
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.automanualsms" == "Manual",
    uiOutput("dayFilterControlForSMS"),
    helpText("Note: SMS will be sent to all customers on selected Days"),
    br(),
    textAreaInput(
      "textSmsMarketingWeekday",
      "Enter campaign text or offers to send: ",
      "Sms Marketing Text",

      "100%",
      "100px",
      resize = "vertical"
    ),
    helpText("Note: Enter a custom offer that you want to send!"),
    br(),

    actionButton(
      "manualSmsCampaign",
      " Launch SMS Campaign",
      icon("envelope"),
      style = "color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color:
      #2e6da4; width: 100%; padding-left: 2dp: margin-right: 5px"
    )
  ),
  hr(),
  ##nested conditional panel #2
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.automanualsms" == "Automatic",

    actionButton(
      "maxSmsCampaign",
      "Campaign for Max Revenue Day",
      style =
        "color: #fff; background-color: #6C7A89; border-color:
      #C0C0C0; width: 100%; padding-left: 2dp: margin: 5dp;"
    ),
    helpText("Note: Campaigns will lauch for day with Max Revenue"),

    br(),
    actionButton(
      "minSmsCampaign",
      "Campaign for Min Revenue Day",
      style =
        "color: #fff; background-color: #6C7A89; border-color:
      #C0C0C0; width: 100%; padding-left: 2dp: margin: 5dp;"
    ),

    helpText("Note: Campaigns will lauch for day with Max Revenue")
  )
)
,

#### Main Conditional Panel for Email Marketing
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.WeekdayMarketingChoice == 'emailMarketing'",
  selectInput(
    "automanualemail",
    "Auto or Manual",
    choices = c("Automatic", "Manual"),
    1
  )
  ,
  #nested conditional panel #1
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.automanualemail" == "Manual",


    uiOutput("dayFilterControlForEmail"),
    helpText("Note: Emails will be sent to all customers on selected Days"),
    br(),
    textAreaInput(
      "textEmailMarketingWeekday",
      "Enter campaign text or offers to send: ",
      "Special Discount Offers!",
      "100%",
      "100px",
      resize = "vertical"
    ),
    helpText("Note: Enter a custom offer that you want to send!"),
    br(),

    actionButton(
      "manualEmailCampaign",
      "Launch Email Campaign",
      icon("envelope"),
      style = "color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4;
      width: 100%; padding-left: 2dp: margin: 5dp;"
    )
    ),
  hr(),
  #helpText("Note: Max and Min Campaigns"),
  # nested conditional panel #2
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.automanualemail" == "Automatic",
    actionButton(
      "maxEmailCampaign",
      "Campaign for Max Revenue Day",
      style =
        "color: #fff; background-color: #6C7A89; border-color:
      #C0C0C0; width: 100%; padding-left: 2dp: margin: 5dp;"
    ),
    helpText("Note: Campaigns will lauch for day with Max Revenue"),


    br(),
    actionButton(
      "minEmailCampaign",
      "Campaign for Min Revenue Day",
      style =
        "color: #fff; background-color: #6C7A89; border-color:
      #C0C0C0; width: 100%; padding-left: 2dp: margin: 5dp;"
    ),
    helpText("Note: Campaigns will lauch for day with Min Revenue"),
    br()
  )

  )
),
```

Comment: Please make sure you code is correctly formatted. Also as a broader comment, but I don't think Shiny is your best call for building an email sign-up form.

Comment: Apologies for the code. Also, this is not a signup form. this will be used to run marketing campaigns

Comment: Marketing campaigns and sign up forms are fairly similar. But the point still stands: why are you using Shiny?  Shiny is intended for interactive data analysis. May be better off using something else

Comment: This is just one feature of the project that i cropped out. The project is meant to do Customer and product segmentation, plus RFM analysis. Includes several ggplots and leaflet maps as well, which i think are well suited to be used with shiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have some of the conditions in your conditional panels formatted correctly and some not. If the condition doesn't evaluate to `TRUE` then the panel doesn't open. However, `conditionalPanel` translates conditions to javascript, so they don't look like standard equality checks in R.

In this case, where you have:

```
conditionalPanel(
  "input.automanualsms" == "Manual",
```

replace with:

```
conditionalPanel(
  "input.automanualsms == 'Manual'",
```

and that will make your nested panels work (and do the same for the other panels you have). The general format is `"input.<inputID> == '<value>'"`. Note that the entire condition is held in double quotes, and the specific value is held in single quotes.